# UITableView нет данных в таблице

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
import UIKit


struct Menu {
    let name:String
}

class MenuOvraide {
    static func menus() -> [Menu]{
        return [Menu(name: "Авиорежим"),Menu(name: "Wi-Fi"),Menu(name: "Звуки")]
    }
}

class TableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TableMenu: UITableView!
    var menus = MenuOvraide.menus()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.TableMenu.delegate = self       
    } 
}

extension TableViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menus.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = TableMenu.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        let menuss = menus[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Добрый день подскажите почему не отображаются данные в в табл вью из массиве вроде код верный может я что то не дописал ?

Comment: Для чего у вас присутствует константа menuss ?

Comment: Он возвращает индекс

Comment: Странно, не вижу, как это происходит  :(

Comment: У меня тоже нечего не выходит

Comment: Просто получается, вы создаете переменную, что-то ей присваиваете и дальше ничего с ней не делаете. Там вам уже ответили, что скорее всего нужно сделать. Нужно как-то задействовать вашу эту переменную. А то она у вас создается просто так, а не для возврата какого-то индекса.

Comment: В `TableViewController.viewDidLoad` не забудьте вызвать `super.viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не вывели данные в ячейки

Если у вас предположим в ячейке есть лейбл для вывода пункта меню `menuTitleLabel`, то нужно дописать `cell.menuTitleLabel.text = menuss.name`

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: @Anis в таком случае поставьте возле ответа галку